# How do I protect the database server?

Tags: php, database, security, passwords

Currently my database user and its password are pretty easily to guess, eg.

database user: dbadmin

database pwd : super + companyname

What and how to generate a secure a secure database password? Using md5 or sha1??

**What are the things that I need to pay attention to secure my database?**

I am using php, thanks

Comment: Also try serverfault.. you may get good answers therer

Comment: On a completely unrelated topic - your profile is practically empty. Can you update it to include, say, your company name? :P

Answer (score 4):

If what you're looking for is just a secure password generator, there are a number of tools for creating strong passwords.  Keepass is one that I use, but you can also look into pwgen, apg, passgen, or others.

- Keepass -- http://keepass.info/
- apg -- http://www.debianadmin.com/automated-password-generator-in-debian.html
- passgen -- http://www.linuxbuilt.com/passwords.php
- pwgen -- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pwgen/

To keep the database secure you also need to consider where you're using the username/password combination in your scripts.  One technique that I've seen used often is to put the credentials in a separate file and to import them everywhere else they're needed.  This way you can put strict access regulations on that one file through your webserver and filesystem security settings.

Security is a layered approach, and the more precautions you take the more resistant your server will be to malicious activity.

Answer (score 3):

Use some kind of pattern to create a password that is complex, but also possible for you to remember.

E.g. Think of a silly sentence and take the first letter of every word.

"16 Butterflys drew straws to see which 5 should become Caterpillars first."

forms the password "16Bdstsw5sbCf".

That's 13 chars long, contains 3 numbers and some upper case chars. That should be pretty strong, and it's much easier to remember than just a random string.

For even better strength, throw some punctuation in there too.

Comment: +1: Great from a security point of view, but on rather shaky ground entomologically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a secure password simply by mashing the keyboard:

```
Z3w947CFqnY39cfo
```

That's as secure as you possibly need - it's immune to dictionary attacks, and long enough to be immune to brute force attacks.

(Of course you'll need to write it down, unless you have a trick memory, but that's always a compromise with passwords - and presumably it will appear in your application code or config anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use phpMyAdmin it has, when you are creating a user, a 'generate password' option.  Try that or you could do something like this:

```
function generatePassword($length) {
    // start with a blank password
    $password = "";
    // define possible characters
    $possible = "0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz"; 
    // set up a counter
    $i = 0; 
    // add random characters to $password until $length is reached
    while ($i < $length) { 
        // pick a random character from the possible ones
        $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
        // we don't want this character if it's already in the password
        if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
            $password .= $char;
            $i++;
        }
     }
     // done!
     return $password;
 }
```